# Not getting correct contour plot of coefficients from my Logistic Regression implementation?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, logistic-regression, contour

I implemented logistic regression and use it on a data set. (This is an exercise in Coursera's ML course Week #3 (which normally uses matlab and octave) using python (so this isn't cheating)).

I started with the implementation in `sklearn` to classify the data set used in week three of this course (http://pastie.org/10872959). Here is a small, reproducible example for anyone to try out what I used (it relies only on `numpy` and `sklearn`):

It takes the data set, splits it into the feature matrix and the output matrix, and then constructs 26 more features **from the original 2** (i.e from

[image]
). I then use logistic regression in `sklearn`, but this does not give the contour plot desired (please see below).

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression as expit
import numpy as np

def thetaFunc(y, theta, x):

    deg = 6

    spot = 0
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, deg + 1):
    for j in range(i + 1):
        sum += theta[spot] * x**(i - j) * y**(j)
        spot += 1
    return sum


def constructVariations(X, deg):

    features = np.zeros((len(X), 27)) 
    spot = 0

    for i in range(1, deg + 1):
        for j in range(i + 1):

            features[:, spot] = X[:,0]**(i - j) * X[:,1]**(j)
            spot += 1

    return features

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.loadtxt("ex2points.txt", delimiter = ",")
    X,Y = np.split(data, [len(data[0,:]) - 1], 1)
    X = reg.constructVariations(X, 6)

    oneArray = np.ones((len(X),1))
    X = np.hstack((oneArray, X))
    trial = expit(solver = 'sag')
    trial = trial.fit(X = X,y = np.ravel(Y))
    print(trial.coef_)

    # everything below has been edited in

    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    txt = open("RegLogTheta", "r").read()
    txt = txt.split()
    theta = np.array(txt, float)

    x = np.linspace(-1, 1.5, 100)
    y = np.linspace(-1,1.5,100)
    z = np.empty((100,100))


    xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    for i in range(len(x)):
         for j in range(len(y)):
             z[i][j] = thetaFunc(yy[i][j], theta, xx[i][j])

    plt.contour(xx,yy,z, levels = [0])
    plt.show()
```

Here are the coefficients of the generic feature terms.
http://pastie.org/10872957 (i.e the coefficients to terms [image]

and the contour it generates:

---

One potential source of error is that I'm misinterpreting the 7 X 4 matrix coefficient matrix stored in `trial._coeff`. I believe that these 28 values are the coefficients to the 28 "variations" above, and I've mapped the coefficients to the variations both column-wise and row-wise. By column-wise, I mean that `[:][0]` get mapped to the first 7 variations, `[:][1]` to the next 7 and so on, and my function `constructVariations` explains how the variations are systematically created. Now the API maintains than an array of `shape (n_classes, n_features)` is stored in `trial._coeff`, so should I infer that `fit` classified the data into four classes? Or have I run through this problem poorly in another way?
[image]

---

*Update*

My interpretation (and/or use) of the weights must be at fault:

Instead of relying on the prediction built into `sklearn`, I myself tried to calculate the values that set the following to 1/2

[image]

[image]

The values of theta are those found from printing `trial._coeff` and x and y are scalars. Those x,y are then plotted to give the contour.

The code I used (but did not originally add in) attempts to do this. What is wrong with the math behind it?

Comment: This is actually a great question, but needs trimming, actually need to reduce detail and summarize, move the actual question to the top and the less-important code to bottom. I retitled it to make it focused and much clearer that this isn't a "Do my homework" type question, which attracts tons of downvotes on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> One potential source of error is that I'm misinterpreting the 7 X 4 matrix coefficient matrix stored in trial._coeff

This matrix is not 7x4, it is 1x28 (check `print(trial.coef_.shape)`). One coefficient for each of your 28 features (27 returned by constructVariations and 1 added manually).

> so should I infer that fit classified the data into four classes?

No, you missinterpreted the array, it has a single row (for binary classificaation there is no point in having two).

> Or have I run through this problem poorly in another way?

Code is fine, interpretation not. In particular, see actual decision boundary from your model (plotted by calling "predict" and plotting contour)

[image: lr]

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression as expit
import numpy as np

def constructVariations(X, deg):

    features = np.zeros((len(X), 27)) 
    spot = 0

    for i in range(1, deg + 1):
        for j in range(i + 1):

            features[:, spot] = X[:,0]**(i - j) * X[:,1]**(j)
            spot += 1

    return features

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.loadtxt("ex2points.txt", delimiter = ",")
    X,Y = np.split(data, [len(data[0,:]) - 1], 1)
    rawX = np.copy(X)    
    X = constructVariations(X, 6)

    oneArray = np.ones((len(X),1))
    X = np.hstack((oneArray, X))
    trial = expit(solver = 'sag')
    trial = trial.fit(X = X,y = np.ravel(Y))
    print(trial.coef_)

    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    h = 0.01
    x_min, x_max = rawX[:, 0].min() - 1, rawX[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = rawX[:, 1].min() - 1, rawX[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

    data = constructVariations(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()], 6)
    oneArray = np.ones((len(data),1))
    data = np.hstack((oneArray, data))
    Z = trial.predict(data)
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)

    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(rawX[:, 0], rawX[:, 1], c=Y, linewidth=0, s=50)
    plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Paired, alpha=0.8)
    plt.show()
```

### Update

In the code provided you forgot (in visualization) that you added column of "1"s to your data representation, thus your thetas are one "off", as theta[0] is a bias, theta[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHsR8.png) is related to your 0'th variable etc.

```
def thetaFunc(y, theta, x):

    deg = 6

    spot = 0
    sum = theta[spot]

    spot += 1
    for i in range(1, deg + 1):
        for j in range(i + 1):
            sum += theta[spot] * x**(i - j) * y**(j)
            spot += 1
    return sum
```

you also forgot about intercept term from logisticregression itself, thus

```
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
for i in range(len(x)):
     for j in range(len(y)):
         z[i][j] = thetaFunc(yy[i][j], theta, xx[i][j])
z -= trial.intercept_
```

[image]

(image generated using fixed code of yours)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression as expit

def thetaFunc(y, theta, x):

    deg = 6

    spot = 0
    sum = theta[spot]

    spot += 1
    for i in range(1, deg + 1):
        for j in range(i + 1):
            sum += theta[spot] * x**(i - j) * y**(j)
            spot += 1
    return np.exp(-sum)


def constructVariations(X, deg):

    features = np.zeros((len(X), 27)) 
    spot = 0

    for i in range(1, deg + 1):
        for j in range(i + 1):

            features[:, spot] = X[:,0]**(i - j) * X[:,1]**(j)
            spot += 1

    return features

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.loadtxt("ex2points.txt", delimiter = ",")
    X,Y = np.split(data, [len(data[0,:]) - 1], 1)

    X = constructVariations(X, 6)
    rawX = np.copy(X)

    oneArray = np.ones((len(X),1))
    X = np.hstack((oneArray, X))
    trial = expit(solver = 'sag')
    trial = trial.fit(X = X,y = np.ravel(Y))

    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    theta = trial.coef_.ravel()

    x = np.linspace(-1, 1.5, 100)
    y = np.linspace(-1,1.5,100)
    z = np.empty((100,100))


    xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    for i in range(len(x)):
         for j in range(len(y)):
             z[i][j] = thetaFunc(yy[i][j], theta, xx[i][j])
    z -= trial.intercept_

    plt.contour(xx,yy,z > 1,cmap=plt.cm.Paired, alpha=0.8)
    plt.scatter(rawX[:, 0], rawX[:, 1], c=Y, linewidth=0, s=50)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I also added my code for plotting the contour. Can you check it out pls?

Comment: This is probably where I make a mistake

Comment: Your corrections include more than just accounting for intercept terms! My code also errs in that I don't return `np.exp(-sum)` but `sum` and, while you plot `plt.contour(xx,yy, z > 1)` (which, I assume, plots level curves greater than 1), I plot `plt.contour(xx, yy, z, levels = [0])`. Why does yours work? My understanding is that the boundary region is determined at those points with g(theta, x, y) = 0 (http://pasteboard.co/1DQI61Z9.png -- from Elements of SL).

Comment: The exp part is not important, i did this during debugging as it was easier for me, but this will work without it too

Comment: At this point, you've answered all my SO relevant questions (thanks!). I've ticked your answer. Maybe more relevant for CV SE: If we are looking for the dot product of weights and features to = 0, then why doesn't returning `sum` work just as well as returning `-sum`?

Comment: It does work. As i said. My modification was just for myself as i prefer to think about it in exp scale. Unless you are asking why we use minus in general?  It comes from mathematical derivation, its more natural this way, otherwise you will model probabiity of the negative result instead of positive. Still works though, your weights have too flip